# Remove extra height (white space in bottom of the page)

Tags: html, css

i have a website https://www.youwintube.com/ , If you look at the bottom of the website there is lot of white space.

So To remove that i went to inspect element in firefox .. there style automatically set like

```
<div style="height: 871px; min-height: 487px;" id="content">
```

but in html template its just

```
<div id="content">
```

So how is this height automatically set , how do i remove it .

Comment: Remove line of code `$("#content").css("height",$.getDocHeight());`.

Comment: i added that line because....when i generate download links...the list goes all way down outside content div..any other options ?

Comment: anyways i commented out that line , still there is extra space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing in your init.js this:

```
var $sc = $('#sidebar, #content'), tid;
```

for this:

```
var $sc = $('#sidebar'), tid;
```